# Error with SMTP Server Time

Tags: java, mysql, email, oracle11g, smtp

- Hi everyone through java i'm calling procedure for mail sending via SMTP Server.
- we know in java code we never give time format SMTP Server only takecare it.
- Im using procedure right in that procedure Im giving again time format.
- hear is the problem ?
- Every thing is right but when im receiving mail the time is different why it is coming different im not sure So please give sum suggestions on this.

Error Ex: Time is 4PM and Im receiving mail is 4PM but it is showing different time like 7PM..????

Comment: Is your mail server in another time zone? Say one thats +3hours from your timezone?

Comment: May be Your given time format and SMTP time format is different or there can be problem about timezone as well

Comment: Can u please provide SMTP server time format

Comment: I have already checked all machines time all are right .

Comment: What Exactly my question is we dont want to give time format all for SMTP Server right  ? it's self only it will take care right ?????

Comment: Show any date-related headers in the *received* message and note the actual time the message was sent, please.  Also the mysql and oracle11g tags seem irrelevant to this question and should be explained or removed, please.